# Problems with sound and flash in Ubuntu 12

Tags: linux, audio

I'm having these problems:

a) I can't have music playing and at the same time watch a video en youtube. If music is playing, flash is muted, and vice versa.

b) Sound has too much bass. I partially solved this with Audacious, because it comes with an equalizer. But that only helps for music played in audacious. Videos played with Movie Player, or anything in flash sounds horrible.

I tried using pulseaudio-equalizer but it was buggy: When enabled, sound was too low, and sometimes it did 'jumps' to normal.

Someone suggested that I should remove pulse, but when I run 'apt-get remove pulseaudio' it tells me it will remove ubuntu-desktop as well.

Any ideas? Rants about pulse/alsa/oss are also welcome, they help me understand what's happening with sound in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled and it works fine now